# React-Router-Dom v5 - Switch doesn't work with mapping array of Route components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have setup `react-router-dom` like in the attached code. Problem is, `Switch` stops working after it has hit `#1` in the code. I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work. It works if I remove `.map()` and do everything manually. With using `.map()`, What I see happening is, The routes defined till the first `navLink` with children (including that navLink, subroutes too) work. After that none of the routes work. In the attached code, the routes after `navLink` with title `Pools` will not work. The first time it deals with the subroutes well, but something breaks after the first time. After that even `navLink` without children wouldn't work. I have tried adding `Switch` components outside each code that using `.map()` but no luck. I tried debugging using Chrome DevTools, what I see is, from the `Switch` component's prepective there are no children after the `navLinks` that work. What could possibly cause this?

Also, In the React devtools, Switch's children are not a flat array, it has nesting in it. Whereas if I did everything manually it will not have nesting.

```
export const Page = () => {
const navLinks = [{
    title: "Data Centers",
    icon: mdiDatabase,
    modelName: "dataCenter",
    url: "/datacenters",
  },
  {
    title: "Pools",
    icon: mdiServerNetwork,
    url: "/pools",
    modelName: "pool",
    children: [
      { title: "Pool Status", url: "/status", modelName: "poolStatus" },
      { title: "Profiles", url: "/profiles", modelName: "poolProfile" },
    ],
  },
  ... 
];

return <Switch>
  {navLinks.map((navLink) => {
    if (navLink.children) {
      // Get the component to render for this table
      const Component = modelToPageMap[navLink.modelName];
      return (
        <>
          {allowedTableNames.includes(navLink.modelName) && (
            <Route path={`${path}${navLink.url}`} exact>
              <Component />
            </Route>
          )}
          {/* #1 Once these routes are mapped once, they broke the route */}
          {navLink.children
            .filter((e) => allowedTableNames.includes(e.modelName))
            .map((child) => {
              // Get the component to render for this table
              const Component = modelToPageMap[child.modelName];
              return (
                <Route path={`${path}${navLink.url}${child.url}`}>
                  <Component />
                </Route>
              );
            })}
        </>
      );
    }

    if (allowedTableNames.includes(navLink.modelName)) {
      const Component = modelToPageMap[navLink.modelName];
      return (
        <Route path={`${path}${navLink.url}`} exact>
          <Component />
        </Route>
      );
    }

    return null;
  })}
</Switch>;
}
```

Hope I explained myself well, please ask if you didn't understand my problem.

Comment: I've never seen a switch outside of a return statement. Usually it is in  the return statement and below the router. I'm also not clear what function is returning all these statements.

Comment: Please have another look, I have edited the code. I just lazily didn't add everything.

Comment: you have no braces around your return statement so your compiler thinks you are just returning "<Switch>".

Comment: And because of that, I can't tell if you are embedding return statements inside of return statements, which I also haven't seen before.

Comment: No no it doesn't. or it would have errored out. Braces are actually optional aswell.

Comment: The return statements are inside the map() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote my code. This time it works, This time I pushed each `Route` into a array and used `flatMap()` to get a flattened array. Works like a charm. I think `React.Fragment` (or `<></>`) I used was causing the problem.

```
export const Page = () => {
  const navLinks = [
    {
      title: "Data Centers",
      icon: mdiDatabase,
      modelName: "dataCenter",
      url: "/datacenters",
    },
    {
      title: "Pools",
      icon: mdiServerNetwork,
      url: "/pools",
      modelName: "pool",
      children: [
        { title: "Pool Status", url: "/status", modelName: "poolStatus" },
        { title: "Profiles", url: "/profiles", modelName: "poolProfile" },
      ],
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Switch>
      {navLinks.flatMap((navLink) => {
        const routes: React.ReactElement[] = [];

        if (allowedTableNames.includes(navLink.modelName)) {
          const Component = modelToPageMap[navLink.modelName];
          routes.push(
            <Route path={`${path}${navLink.url}`} exact>
              <Component />
            </Route>
          );
        }

        if (navLink.children) {
          routes.push(
            ...navLink.children
              .filter((e) => allowedTableNames.includes(e.modelName))
              .map((child) => {
                const Component = modelToPageMap[child.modelName];
                return (
                  <Route path={`${path}${navLink.url}${child.url}`} exact>
                    <Component />
                  </Route>
                );
              })
          );
        }

        return routes;
      })}
    </Switch>
  );
};
```